# Lint tools in C and C++ (and possibly Objective-C)

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, vim, syntastic

I use Vim as my IDE and one of the most useful plugins I have for it is Syntastic which allows code analysis and error reporting without having to compile the program.

It supports the following checkers:

- Splint
- checkpatch
- oclint
- sparse
- ycm

The question is which one is the best? I use modern C and C++ (C11 and C++11) and would like something similar to the clang static analyser (unfortunately clang_complete conflicts with one of my other plugins and I don't have the time to fix it). So any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK after pretty much trying them all YCM is clearly the best. It completely replaces clang_complete and supertab which were two other plugins that I used to use and further more it integrates nicely with Syntastic and uses the clang static analyser. I'm very impressed with it.